# How can I bring up a python shell with packages already imported with a python script?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to bring up a python window (could be idle or cmd based) with some packages already imported by double clicking a python script. Is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  You want something like this:

```
import sys
import code

preloaded_modules = dict(sys=sys)

code.interact(local=preloaded_modules)
```

When you put the above code in a file and run it, you'll see a traditional Python REPL (interactive interpreter), except the `sys` module will already be loaded.  You can add more modules to your REPL by importing them into your script and adding them to the `preloaded_modules` dictionary.

The code module also has tools to build all kinds of custom interpreters.

More info here: [Python code module](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html)

(NOTE: the above refs Python 2.x, but it should be mostly the same in 3.x)

Comment: what should be the key and what should be the value in the dictionary?

Comment: @esotericallyillin the value should be the module you want to have available, and the key should be the name you want the module to have in your new REPL

Answer (score 5):

You can use the -i interpreter option. `python -c "import os" -i` will import the os module and go to the interpreter read/eval loop.

You can also put some statements (imports, definitions, etc) on a file and load it with `python -i <file.py>`

Comment: Python 3.3 added shebang support on Windows. Otherwise you can install pylauncher separately. Then just use a shebang in your importing script with the '-i' option, such as `#!python3 -i`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable

[from docs:](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)

> PYTHONSTARTUP If this is the name of a readable file, the Python
>   commands in that file are executed before the first prompt is
>   displayed in interactive mode. The file is executed in the same
>   namespace where interactive commands are executed so that objects
>   defined or imported in it can be used without qualification in the
>   interactive session. You can also change the prompts sys.ps1 and
>   sys.ps2 in this file.

and if want more drastic change like some initializaton whenever python is run, you can modify [site.py](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) or create your own `pth` files